# Is there alternative to tools like MIPT and Discover in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapinfo

I am getting fond of QGIS but I am unable to find tools for frequency plannig and other stuff. Are there any alternative to MIPT and Discover of Mapinfo in QGIS?

MIPT is used for frequency planning in telecom. It creates cell sector and is useful for neighbour correlation. and discover has link [here](http://www.encom.com.au/template2.asp?pageid=9). and more [information](http://www.pbinsight.com.au/support/training/video-tutorials/product/encom-discover/)

Comment: What does exactly do this tool? What are the inputs, operations and outputs?

Comment: @GiovanniManghi sorry for incomplete information I have edited :)!

Comment: I don't know anything about this field. But I remember this tools for QGIS http://www.qrap.org.za/ can be useful?

Comment: @GiovanniManghi it's only for ubuntu :(

Comment: Anyway it is the right tool? About the platform... there is the source code and you can always give Linux a try... ;)

Comment: @GiovanniManghi yes it is but I am on windows centric platform :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this tool http://www.qrap.org.za/ should do what is required. The source is available (is a C++ plugin for QGIS) but a binary is available only for Linux. Try contact the author and see if they provide support for Windows.